# How to use Radix UP501 gps module with arduino

Tags: arduino, gps

I bought Radix [UP501](http://www.adafruit.com/datasheets/UP501_brochure_rev_1_2.pdf) module . but i don't know how to use it with my arduino to output the location data on serial monitor .. How to make it working ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just went through something similar. Here's what you're going to want to do. Connect the following:

```
UP501::Pin2 (TX)    <--> Arduino::D10 (doesn't matter too much which pin)
UP501::Pin3 (GND)   <--> Arduino::GND
UP501::Pin4 (Power) <--> Arduino::3.3V
```

You probably will want to also put a 4.7uF capacitor (at least) between 3.3V and GND to the module (so you could bring the Arduino 3.3V and GND to a breadboard first, for example, and then go from the breadboard to the module). You can safely leave the other pins disconnected.

Use the SoftwareSerial example sketch and modify it something like this:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial mySerial(10, 11); // RX, TX ... the 10 is what matters based on my suggested wiring above

void setup()  
{
  // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(57600); 
  Serial.println("Goodnight moon!");

  // set the data rate for the SoftwareSerial port
  mySerial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() // run over and over
{
  if (mySerial.available())
    Serial.write(mySerial.read());
}
```

This will echo whatever the GPS is saying (at 9600 baud) to your Serial Monitor (at 57600 baud).  Even though the GPS is running at 3.3V, the Arduino should still be able to listen to it without an issue.